# VPN disconnect after disconnecting from remote desktop

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop

I'm copying a 6GB file via VPN. I'm doing so via a Remote Desktop connection on Windows Server 2016.

When I stay connected, the entire file has been copied.

But when I exit Remote Desktop, the VPN connection disconnects after some time and the copying stops.

What to do to prevent VPN disconnection?